# decrypt md5 iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, md5

I'm using the following code to encrypt a string using md5

```
const char* str = [@"123456" UTF8String];
unsigned char result[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
CC_MD5(str, strlen(str), result);

NSMutableString *ret = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH*2];
for(int i = 0; i<CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; i++) {
    [ret appendFormat:@"%02x",result[i]];
}
NSLog(@"%@", ret);
```

now I want a source code to decrypt the coded string, Any Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't decrypt an MD5 HASH, it is a oneway encryption.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is not an Encryption. 
It is a hash function.
Finding the original value from a hash function is in general not possible.